# Post and get in a same jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

In my Django app I would like to be able to post and get in a same jQuery request.

My HTML:

```
    <form  method="post" id='validation_form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input id='username' type="text" name="username" value=""/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
   var username = $('#username').val()
   $.post('/auth_validate', {'username': username}, function(data) { 
   // Get Request to get something.
   }
```

Views:

```
   def auth_validate(request):
       error = False
       if request.method == 'POST':
           username = request.POST.get('username')

           if User.objects.filter(username__exact=username).exists():
               error = 'Sorry this username is already taken'
```

I would like to get 'error' in the same jQuery request I used to post. Is it possible to do that?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Here is the solution I found.

JS:

```
  function validateForm() {
    var username = $('#username').val()
    var result=''
    $.get('/auth_validate_username/', {'result':result}, function(data){
       $.post('/auth_validate_username/', {'username': username}, function(data) { 
       $('#error_message').html(data); 
      });
    });
    return false;
    };
```

html:

```
   <form  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input id='username' type="text" name="username" value=""/>
        <div id='error_message'></div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

views:

```
    def auth_validate_username(request):
       result = ''
       if request.method == 'POST':
          username = request.POST.get('username')
          if User.objects.filter(username=username):
             result='Sorry but this name is already taken'

    return HttpResponse(result)
```

This way I first post the value username. If the username already exists result changes, and then I get it.

The trick was to put a post request inside a get request.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your view, but that is probably just a copy&paste problem, right?

Comment: Yes it is. I corrected it.

Comment: You could return a `JSON` response that includes the status ("everything OK" or "error") and the error message ("username already taken", "username too short / long"...)

Comment: I do not quite get it. Do you want to send some information to the server via POST and return to client with `Sorry this username is already taken`?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Ok, thank you. But I don't know how to do that. Do you have any tutorial where I can learn that?

Comment: @Amberlamps The idea is to check if the username is already taken or not. I need to post the value of the input to the server, check in my view if the username exists or not and then return 'Sorry...' if the username is taken and 'False' if not.

Comment: You just need to construct a `dict` with the appropriate keys, and eventually return `HttpResponse(json.dumps(the_dict))`.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Ok, but how do I get this dict back in my jquery function?

Comment: @Marcolac: Your title is totally misleading then. You have a single request (post-request) and you are asking how to get the answer from the server. I do not know what the response object looks like in Django, but it has to look something like `response.send('Sorry. Error')`. And to fetch the response, Dolondro proposed a very standard and good solution to that.

Comment: @Marcolac Well, you just parse the JSON that's in the response (`data`).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I already tried that but I had an error. I just posted a question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956910/ajax-command-and-json-response

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the $.post, use the $.ajax command. They do exactly the same things, but $.ajax gives you more features to play with.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/auth_validate",
  data: {
    'username': username
  },
  success: function(data){
    //There was successfully data here!
  },
  error: function(xhr, data, error){
    //An error was thrown!
  }
});
```

Then add a line that will return a 403 (or similar) HTTP error code just above this line (I would supply it but I'm not familiar with the ins and outs of Django):

```
error = 'Sorry this username is already taken'
```

That way your successful messages will be routed through the success handler and your errors will be routed through the error handler.

Comment: This is exactly what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If with *get* you mean the `GET` method, why not adding your query directly in the url parameter?

```
  var username = $('#username').val()
   $.post('/auth_validate?myvar=thevalue', {'username': username}, function(data) { 
   // Get Request to get something.
   }
```

But maybe I'm misunderstooding the question...

Answer (score 0):

You could return an http code 400 (Bad Request) and add an error handler for you `post` request, that should do the trick.

I'm not very familiar with django so I'm just giving you the abstract idea.

Comment: Returning HTTP 500 for non-errors is going to get you a lot of email error reports in Django.

Comment: @Thomas Orozco: yes, 400 seems more suitable. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at [the dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) [API](http://django-dajax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html). This would do the job.