# $ajax command and Json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

In my django app I try to use ajax in order to check if a username already exists and display an error if it is the case.

Here is what I have

html:

```
 <form  method="post" id='my_form'>
 {% csrf_token %}
    <input id='username' type="text" name="username"/>
 <button type="submit">Valider</button>
 </form>
```

js:

```
  $('#my_form').submit(function(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    if (username == ''){
       alert('please enter username');
       return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/auth_validate",
           data: {'username': $('#username').val(), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
           dataType: "text",
           success: function(response) {
                  var response = $.parseJSON(response);
                  if (response.success){
                      return true;
                  }
                  else{
                      alert(response.error);
                      return false;
                  }
            },
            error: function(rs, e) {
                   alert(rs.responseText);
                   return false;
            }
      }); 
})
```

views:

```
def auth_validate(request):
    error = ''
    success = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        if not username:
            error = _('Please enter username')
        elif User.objects.filter(username__exact=username).exists():
            error = _('Sorry this username is already taken')
        else:
            success = True

    ajax_vars = {'success': success, 'error': error}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(ajax_vars), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

When I enter a username (if it exists or not) an empty alert appears and when I click on 'ok', the form is submitted.
Moreover, the errors do not appear.

Any idea on why it doesn't work?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you should always add a return false after your $.ajax block, otherwise you'll get your form submitted anyway.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I edited it. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view and template look fine
I suggest that you use the native `JSON` handling the function has and serialize the form instead of "sending" `data` manually. Also please note the `return false` at the end of the event callback, instead of inside the `success` and `error` callbacks.

```
$('#my_form').on('submit', function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/auth_validate",
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (!response.success) {
                alert(response.error);
            } else {
                alert('This username is available!');
            }
        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
            alert(rs.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Good luck :)

**UPDATE:**

Please check the else in the success callback ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I try this solution I have a huge alert box appearing with a very large error message that begins like that: TypeError at /auth_validate/
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10cb43cd0> is not JSON serializable    Any idea on where the problem comes from?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a dpaste/gist with the full stacktrace so I or someone else can help? (please don't paste it here)

Comment: Ok it works. I just had a very big error_message because I worked locally and had Debug to True. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: But I don't have the text 'Please enter username'  or 'Sorry this username...' I just have an internal server error when the username is empty or taken, and nothing happens if the username is not taken.

Comment: Your view doesn't give any of those error messages back in case of server error; you are handling validation errors via `HttpResponse`s, so you should handle server errors apart.

I mean, the errors messages are all handled in the success callback. Error callback is for when the request crashes for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this part:

```
         var response = $.parseJSON(response);
          if (response.success){
              return true;
          }
          else{
              alert(response.error);
          }
```

response doesn't have a value 'success', so an emply alert dialog pops up. jQuery already takes care, that this check is only done when the request was sucesssful, so you don't to do it.

If you don't want to use the browser submit of the for, add `return false;` at the end of your funciton to prefent the browser default behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem because the alert that pops up is the one of the error function. If I delete the first part of my function (sucess: function...), the empty alert still appears.

Comment: I tried to put a return false; at the end of my ajax function. But when I post something I now have a 403 error, and a popup explaining that this is due to a csrf token problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does the JSON look like that django is responding with?

Do you know which alert is getting called? Is it the one in the error function or the success function?

I don't think you need this line

```
var response = $.parseJSON(response);
```

the response should already be JSON.